# DHT11 Sensor Code Fatal Error

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, temperature-sensor

I recently tried using Hobbyist.co.nz's guide on the DHT11 sensor. I installed the Adafruit_Sensor and DHT11 Sensor libraries,  but it keeps returning with a fatal error.

Here is the code and the error:

```
#include <dht.h>

#define dht_dpin A0 //no ; here. Set equal to channel sensor is on

dht DHT;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(300);//Let system settle
  Serial.println("Humidity and temperature\n\n");
  delay(700);//Wait rest of 1000ms recommended delay before
  //accessing sensor
}//end "setup()"

void loop(){
  //This is the "heart" of the program.
  DHT.read11(dht_dpin);

    Serial.print("Current humidity = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
    Serial.print("%  ");
    Serial.print("temperature = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.temperature); 
    Serial.println("C  ");
  delay(800);//Don't try to access too frequently... in theory
  //should be once per two seconds, fastest,
  //but seems to work after 0.8 second.
}// end loop()
```

> ```
> C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\Arduino\sketch_dec19c\sketch_dec19c.ino:2:17:
> ```
>
> fatal error: dht.h: No such file or directory
>
> ```
> #include <dht.h>
> ```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using [Adafriut's DHT library](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHTtester/DHTtester.ino).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The examples I can see from Adafruit say

```
#include "DHT.h"
```

or

```
#include <DHT.h>
```

But you wrote

```
#include <dht.h>
```

They aren't the same.

Further, the examples for the Adafruit library show usage like:

```
  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
```

But you call `DHT.temperature` and `DHT.humidity`.

If you are meaning to use the Adafruit library, you have to write your code according to their documentation.

Also of note, you have defined the type of the object as `dht` and the name as `DHT`, but for Adafruit, the type is `DHT`.

**EDIT:**

The example on the website you note has a downloadable zip file for the DHT library they use. You cannot assume that all libraries for interfacing a certain sensor will all have the same programming interface.